# How to use bear with make to auto-create the json compilation database?

Tags: vim, makefile, gtk, gnu-make, youcompleteme

I'm using vim with [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#c-family-semantic-completion) (YCM) plugin for C programming. YCM needs a json file to show code completion suggestions or a manually crafted `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file.
Build systems like `cmake` and `ninja` provide a switch to generate the json file while building but there is no such option for `make`.   [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) is a utility to generate the **JSON compilation database**.
How can I integrate `bear` with my `Makefile`? Should I call `make all` in which bear is an external utility or should I instead call `bear make`? I'm a little confused by its [guide](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear#how-to-use).

For example, [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5) is the a basic example of GTK+. I can compile the code using `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-0 example-0.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `` .
How can I automate the process of **1- compiling and 2- creating the json file** if I want to use `make` as my build system? What should be in my `Makefile`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to feed `bear` every command you use to build from source. For example, you require `configure` script to be run before `make` , first do `bear ./configure` then `bear make`. Make sure the source folder used to build is not processed earlier with some script (like `configure`) because it may affect the json file contents.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't able to install Bear or compiledb easily, maybe a web app is an option.

I've built a simple web app to generate `compile_commands.json`, all you need to have is the output of `make`, e.g., `make --print-directory -n`. The web app is https://texttoolkit.com/compilation-database-generator.